# SQL Alphabetical Select Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, alphabetical

I just wanted to know if it's possible to write a SQL statement that can select rows by columns that contain characters starting with letters that appear later in the alphabet

Say I have the table

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    d_idno SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    d_idch CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    d_desc CHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```

With the following data inside it

```
INSERT INTO data (d_idch, d_desc)
VALUES('BLK', 'black item'),
      ('PNK', 'pink item'),
      ('GRN', 'green item'),
      ('BLU', 'blue item'),
      ('CYA', 'cyan item');
```

I would like to execute a SQL statement along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE d_idch > 'BL'    # I'd like to find a way to replace this line
ORDER BY d_idch
```

This is wrong of course but I would like to select every row that follow after the rows that contain the chars 'BL' when ordered alphabetically

Comment: Why is that wrong? That will select every row that has 'BL' and greater.

Comment: Yeah but I'd like it to not include rows that have BL, I want rows that contain the first two chars that follow later in the alphabet

Comment: Preferably not using WHERE d_idch > 'BM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another condition on your `WHERE` clause to keep the `BL` results out:

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE 
  d_idch > 'BL' 
  AND SUBSTRING(d_idch FROM 1 FOR 2) <> 'BL'
ORDER BY d_idch
```

This way you get everything greater than `BL` but not anything starting with `BL`

As an alternative, you could stick `ZZZZZZ` at the end of your `BL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE d_idch > 'BLZZZZ'  
ORDER BY d_idch
```

And one more alternative, which I think is probably closer to what you are looking for (all have the same results though):

```
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE 
  SUBSTRING(d_idch FROM 1 FOR 2) > 'BL'  
ORDER BY d_idch
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12b56/9)

If the table is HUGE, you might find that second one to be the fastest since your DB doesn't have to `substring` every `d_idch` as part of the logic. Trade offs...

Comment: Ah, substring looks like exactly what I need, I just don't like using SQL which isn't clear so substring I can be more specific. The 3rd answer is perfect, thanks a bunch

Comment: The db is very huge which is why I want to use this to go through tables bits at a time, run queries on rows A to E then F to J etc. Thanks for your help